# I wonder is there any difference between "half of what" and "half what."

Tags: grammar

The original text I read "More than half **of** what he said sounded like a foreign lanugage."

I can't help but think that the sentence without **'of'** is possible, too;

"More than half what he said sounded like a foreign lanugage."

Is there any difference? Or Is the first one is the only right one?

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: I believe this question is [off topic here](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). It is well suited to [ell.se], if a Mod would be so kind as to migrate it.

Comment: Why do you think that "of" can be omitted? Saying "I can't help but think" isn't really a reason. [Please explain](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please). (You should also [cite the source of the quoted text](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1084/so-you-found-a-sentence-or-phrase-why-you-should-cite-your-source). I know that this question was migrated, but these things are expected on ELL.)

Comment: You need the "of" here in standard English.  It might be acceptable to drop it in some regional dialects or in informal speech - it would still be understood.

Comment: “What do you want on the pizza?”  “Half mushroom …”  “And half what?”

Answer (score 1):

It's not a strict rule, but we tend to refer to quantities without the 'of'. For example, "*I drank half a pint of milk*" describes the quantity of milk you drank. "Half a pint" is an accepted measure. You *could* say "*I drank half **of** a pint of milk*", but it sounds like you attempted to drink a pint and only managed half of it.

Closer to your example - imagine you are at lunch with a friend, and his meal arrives. If you said "*I want half what he has*", that could mean you want the same meal, but a portion only half the size. If you said "*I want half **of** what he has*", that sounds like you want to eat half of his meal.